# Change SE Linux context label of a specific folder inside a cifs mount

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mount, cifs, selinux

I have cifs mount on my setup mounted via /etc/fstab with context set to  **system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0**.
There are **some specific folders** that I want to override default context to **set public_content_t** so I can share those folders between httpd and cifs processes.

1) I don't want mount entire mount point with public_content_t.

2) I don't want to set SE bool to make httpd access cifs.

I tried overriding semanage fcontext and chcon and tried many things for days now. It seems like SE Linux capability is run out to make the change satisfying 1) and 2)
Can anyone please help me to give pointers or your kind advice's?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: As much as I hate to admit, this can't be done. So accepting the only answer that mentioned this can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can't be done. I'd like to be proven wrong though, but I was dealing with the same issue about a year ago and I ended up having to create a subfolder under the NFS share and mount that sub-directory as a separate mount point with the desired context

Comment: Thanks Tomas . Yes I also believe this can't be done after trying so many options. Well lets just wait couple of days to see if any advanced super users can advice on this.